# Angular Material Tab label with Image and custom height

Tags: css, angular-material, tabs

I'm trying to set images as labels for Angular Material Tabs. I can set the image like this

```
<mat-tab-group  dynamicHeight>
  <mat-tab> 
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <img src="assets/prueba.jpg"/>
    </ng-template>Content 1 </mat-tab>
```

But this doesn't resize the tab label to the height of the image. How can I acomplish that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Following this link [best-way-to-overwrite-angular-materials-styles](https://betterprogramming.pub/best-way-to-overwrite-angular-materials-styles-e38dc8b84962) I added this code to my `styles.css`:

```
mat-tab-header {
 &.mat-mdc-tab-header {
    --mdc-secondary-navigation-tab-container-height: 142px;
  }
}
```

et voilá!